# Compare Custom Date Format and 'dd/MM/yyyy' format dates in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-comparison

I have the following two date controls in my code:

- Standard Date Control with fixed format: 23/08/2019 (`dd/MM/yyyy`).
- Custom Date Control with flexible format: 08/23/2019 (It can be any of the following formats:
  `'M/d/yy' 
  'M/d/yyyy' 
  'MM/dd/yy' 
  'MM/dd/yyyy
  'dd.MM.yy' 
  'dd/MM/yy' 
  'dd/MM/yyyy' 
  'dd/MMM/yyyy' 
  'dd-MM-yy'
  'yy/MM/dd' 
  'yyyy-MM-dd'` )

I need to compare these two dates to check if one is greater than other. I tried to use `Date.parse()` method but it is not working of most of the formats and is giving Nan error. i have the date format value with me as an hidden field.

```
var standardDateToValidate = '23/08/2019';
var customDateToValidate = '08/23/2019';
if (Date.parse(standardDateToValidate) > Date.parse(customDateToValidate)) {
//to do after the comparison
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update:** As suggested by @LouysPatriceBessette, I modified the code to use moment.js and I'm also getting the user format but it is giving null. Here is the updated code:

```html
<script src='https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js'></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  
  <script>
  var standardDateToValidate = $('#standardDate').val();
  var customDateToValidate = $('#customDate').val();
  var format = 'dd.MM.yy';
  
  function ProcessDate(){
    var a = moment(standardDateToValidate, format);
    var b = moment(customDateToValidate, format);
  
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);
  
    $('#standardDateFormatted').text('1');
    $('#customDateFormatted').text('1');
  }
  </script>
  
<div>
Standard Date:
<span id='standardDate'>23/08/2019</span> <br />
Custom Date:
<span id='customDate'> 08/23/2019</span>  <br /><br />


Formatted Standard Date:
<span id='standardDateFormatted'></span> <br />
Formatted Custom Date:
<span id='customDateFormatted'> </span>

 <br /> <br />
<button onClick='ProcessDate();'>Format Date</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to find a way to know the format of the custom date... Then, I would suggest you to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) for whatever comparison or manipulation.

Comment: If `customDateToValidate` is '09/02/2019' there's no way for javascript to know if it's referring to February 9th 2019 or September 2nd 2019. So as @LouysPatriceBessette says, javascript must know in which format `customDateToValidate` is given.

Comment: There is no reliable way for this unless you have the string **and** the format.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have the date format value and tried moment.js but it is giving null.

Comment: @iSahilSharma If you want to get the text inside one `<span>` tag, you need to use the [`.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function, and don't try to call them before the page load. Just to make sure, add `standardDateToValidate` and `customDateToValidate ` attribution inside the `ProcessDate` method.